# Не работает сессия, чтобы можно было заходить только с одной странице на admin_start.php

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать правильно сессию для перехода с одной страницы на другую. Чтобы можно было заходить на определенную страницу только с одной другой определенной страницы. Делал сессию, работало:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['access'] = TRUE; 
?>
```

На другой странице на которую переход, код такой:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (! isset($_SESSION['access']))
{  
  exit(0);
}
unset($_SESSION['access']);
 ?>
```

Потом когда переехал на другой хостер, пишет такую ошибку:

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/h812299477/helpsetup.ru/docs/adminremotely.php:1) in /home/h856599477/мойсайт.ru/docs/adminremotely.php on line 3
```

На той странице куда переход делается, такая ошибка:

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/h856599477/мойсайт.ru/docs/remoteadmin/admin_start.php:3) in /home/h856599477/мойсайт.ru/docs/remoteadmin/admin_start.php on line 5
```

Помогите пожалуйста, я так понимаю это надо путь указать полностью но Я не понимаю как это сделать ? Если есть у кого желание помочь, надо чтоб эта сессия работала.

Comment: headers already sent означает, что PHP уже отправил заголовки пользователю (а для работы сесий нужно передать пользователю специальные заголовки). Это произошло из-за того, что где-то до вызова `session_start` был какой-то вывод. Это может быть перенос строки перед дескриптором `<?php` или вывод сообщения об ошибке или что-то ещё в таком духе.

Comment: Если до открытия сессии есть какой-либо вывод echo "..."; то это тоже приведёт к ошибке.

Comment: Там этот код стоит на самом верху, там нет ничего, он первый идет.

Comment: @Helpsetup что у вас в admin_start.php на 3й тстроке?

Comment: Лучше добавтье в вопрос листинг admin_start.php, самого начала

Comment: Так то можно и без сессии но будут любопытные лазить. Там ничего плохого нет, простая авторизация через вк и страница для скачивания клиента.

Comment: Некоторые когда делаешь помогаешь удаленно, после того как сделал просто отключаются и пропадают. Чтоб такого не происходило Я предупреждаю что пройдите авторизацию для того чтобы знать вашу страницу вк. Там нет ничего плохого, не какие пароли и прочее не собираются если вы об этом, сайт существует уже года 4 и просто чтобы вылитить из поиска из за какой то херн... у поисковиков с этим все ровно они проверяют сайты.

Comment: Выше этого кода нет ничего, этот код сессии идет первым на странице. Там нет никаких выводов об ошибках и прочего он первый на странице и такой как Я выше его выложил. Да жаль конечно что не кто не поможет, обычно если сразу не помогли а отговорками пишут, значит дальше результата не будет не какого.